# Does assigning return value from a lambda cause a copy?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++14

I have used this pattern before to do module-specific initialization, e.g. at the top of a .cpp file:

```
static bool isInitialized = []()
{
    ...//do stuff
    return true;
}();
```

But what about something like:

```
static MyObject something = []()
{
    MyObject ret(...);
    ret.x(...)
    return ret;
}();
```

Is it definitive if `something` will *be* `ret`, or will be a copy? I want to avoid copying.

I'm working with VS2017/C++14 mainly, though moving to C++17 soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case one should not be a copy in C++17.  You are returning a prvalue, so no temporary is created and instead `isInitialized` is directly constructed.  In C++14 this is only an optional optimization.

Case two is using a named variable so you would have to rely on NRVO, which is not guaranteed in any version of C++, to do that optimization.  On the "plus" side, function local arguments are treated as rvalues in a return statement so `ret` will be moved if it can, and only copied if it can't.

Comment: On the positive side, there's a proposal to guarantee NRVO.

To OP, you can check whether a copy constructor is called or not. A trivial example on compiler explorer (though using modern versions of MSVC) show that copy elision (NRVO) does occur.